# URLConnection when device is in sleep mode not working

Tags: java, android

I am having problems with a background service while the device is in sleep mode. I have set an alarm that will start a service every morning at 9 AM. This service works fine while the device is awake, but fails when the device is asleep.

I've traced the issue to a URLConnection.openConnection() call shown below. The device cannot seem to open this connection while in sleep mode, it throws an IOException. <strike>I've used URL.openStream() to perform network calls when the device is asleep, and they work fine.</strike>

Can anyone explain why openStream() would work in sleep mode but openConnection() does not? Is there a way to get it working?

This works in sleep mode:

return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()), 8192);

This does not seem to work in sleep mode:

```
URL actualURL = new URL(url.toString());
URLConnection c = actualURL.openConnection();
c.setConnectTimeout(10000);
c.setReadTimeout(20000);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream());
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `URLConnection` code from the background thread to the service fixed the issue and it now works while in sleep mode. Logging was working in the thread in sleep mode, but not `openConnection()`.